# Como adicionar outra coluna à minha query que se encontra noutra tabela

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT  DEPARTMENT_ID
    ,(SELECT DEPARTMENT_NAME FROM HR.DEPARTMENTS) AS 'Nome do Departamento'
    ,MIN(SALARY) AS 'salario minimo'
    ,MAX(SALARY) AS 'salario maximo'
    ,CAST(AVG(SALARY) AS NUMERIC(8,2)) AS 'salario medio'
FROM [HR].[EMPLOYEES]
GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_ID
```

Antes de mais sou apenas um iniciado em sql-server! Quero que colocar o nome do departamento ao lado do seu ID, o problema é que me dá o seguinte erro:
"Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse erro ocorre por gerar mais de um resultado no subselect porque ele está sem nenhum tipo de filtragem, sugiro por um where, exemplo

```
SELECT  DEPARTMENT_ID
    ,(SELECT nome_dep FROM HR.DEPARTMENTS where id_hr.departments = DEPARTMENT_ID) AS 'Nome do Departamento'
    ,MIN(SALARY) AS 'salario minimo'
    ,MAX(SALARY) AS 'salario maximo'
    ,CAST(AVG(SALARY) AS NUMERIC(8,2)) AS 'salario medio'
FROM [HR].[EMPLOYEES]
GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_ID
```